# Fetch Query String From URL and Pass It to Href

Tags: javascript, html

I saw several possible solutions to my problem here but somehow I fail to find appropriate solution.

My scenario is this:

User comes to pageA carrying query string in url.

It looks like this:
http://example.com?name=xxxxx&email=xxxxx&a1=1xxxxx

On that page I have two links, lets say their IDs are linkA and linkB.

I am interested in first one with the markup like this:

```
<a href="" id="linkA">Link A</a>
```

I need to fetch entire query string from url and add it to linkA which will point to another URL.
So the final link looks like this:

```
<a href="http://anotherurl.com?name=xxxxx&email=xxxxx&a1=1xxxxx" id="linkA">Link A</a>
```

Can you help me out with clean solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can get the current url using `document.URL` and pick the query params.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need to get the current page's URL, transform it, and assign it to the link tag?

Comment: Or possible you need the other page URL(Page B), and put this URL in <a> tag of page(A)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use [`window.location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to access the entire query string from the page's URL. It will return something like this: `?name=xxxxx&email=xxxxx&a1=1xxxxx`.

You can then append that to your anchor element's `href` attribute, e.g.

```
document.querySelector('#linkA').href = `http://anotherurl.com/${window.location.search}`;
```

If you need an ES5-based solution, this will work:

```
document.querySelector('#linkA').href = 'http://anotherurl.com/' + window.location.search;
```

Comment: I love template strings :3

Comment: Thank you very much! This neatly solves my problem.

Comment: @Riven Me too :) especially when most browsers today support ES6: and even if they don't, you can just use a transpiler.

Comment: @SinisaBajic Glad my answer helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using search key of window.location which returns the search query of the current url.

So, on http://example.com/?name=xxxxx&email=xxxxx&a1=1xxxxx, using the following

```
window.location.search
```

will give you the following string

```
?name=xxxxx&email=xxxxx&a1=1xxxxx
```

You could then append this string to the "href" of the second anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var parameters = window.location.search;
    var link = $('#linkA').attr('href');
    $('#linkA').attr('href', link + parameters);
});
```